# Solr Schema advice in multitenant ecommerce site

Tags: solr

I have a multitenant site, whose products are indexed in Solr, so visitors can search by product name, or any other product property.
Now, I would like to filter by product price.

There are two problems:

1. Not all tentants have the same products on their website.
2. The product price can differ from one customer to another, as each tenant can change the price of each of the product it uses.

So given a tenantId, I'd like to search for all products that tenant has, which are in a given price range.

I don't think I can store a Map<CustomerId, Price> for each product and somehow query that, so I'm a bit stuck on how to design the schema. At the  moment, I just have, for each product, a multivalued property called customer, so I can just filter by all products of a given tentant.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you have one document for each tenant, product-combination? Another option is to have a multi valued list of tenant ids as you have now, and then have dynamic fields for the fields that can vary between tenants; i.e. `price_<tenant_id>` - this allows you to do any operation on tenant specific fields. Make sure you enable doc values for those dynamic fields.

Comment: @MatsLindh I acutally like the first option. But I'm only using data-import tool, I'm not feeding solr through POST requests. I would have to change the system quite a bit, but may be worth it. And I would end up with around 250 milion documents.

Comment: You should be able to do it through DIH as well, but migrating to a custom feeding solution is recommended if you're going to work through 250m documents. The first thing would be to use a composite id of `<tenant id, product id>`, which you can achieve through CONCAT in SQL.